# ENT_QUOTES in a JS string

Tags: javascript, html-encode

I have this function :

```
function change_this(my_str)
{
    $('#myDiv').html('<input value=\''+my_str+'\'>');
}
```

When I call this function with this :

```
onclick=change_this('Test &#039;');
```

I see in the debugger that `&#039;` has been turned to a quote, and therefore the script does not work.

So my question is: how can I send a quote inside a string to a JS function?

I'm sure I'm not the first person to face this issue, I googled but did not find any simple explanations / answers.

Comment: use this `$('#myDiv').html('<input value='+my_str+'>');`

Comment: @tzafar — `my_str` contains a space, so that will prematurely terminate the attribute value.

Comment: Avoid this particular problem by using `"` instead of `'` inside the `input value` part. (You then have the same problem, though, with `&#34;`.)

Comment: Where do you have this function? In an external script?

Comment: tzafar : as Quentin said, your answer is not the solution.

Jongware : as you said, your answer is not the solution

Bergi : the function is in the same page .. I don't see what it would change if it was external, though.

Comment: @Vincent: External scripts are not subject to html entity parsing. But `<script>&quot;</script>` is just the same as `<script>"</script>` iirc.

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems. This is because you have HTML embedded in JavaScript embedded in HTML which you are then generating HTML from by mashing together strings of JavaScript. You switch languages so many often it makes my head spin.

### Problem 1: Getting the right string into the function

To include a single quote inside a string delimited by single quotes in JavaScript, you must escape them with a `\`.

```
onclick="change_this('Test \'');"
```

There is no need to use character references here. There are no `'` with special meaning in the HTML. You would need to use `&#039;` three times if you had used `'` instead of `"` to delimit the attribute value.

I'd avoid `onclick` entirely and favour `data-` attributes and JS event binding.

```
<input type="button" data-foo="Test '">

$("[type=button]").on('click', function (event) {
    change_this( $(this).data('foo') );
});
```

### Problem 2: Getting the right string into the HTML attribute value.

With the approach you are taking, you would need to convert the `'` to `&#039;`. Note that you would have to do it programatically because if you had it in the `onclick` attribute then it would be converted to `'` by the HTML parser before the JavaScript engine even saw it.

Don't use your current approach though. Mashing strings together to make HTML is a nightmare.

Use DOM or something jQuery that vaguely resembles DOM.

```
var input = $("<input />").val(my_str);
$('#myDiv').empty().append(input);
```